# Lightswitch Forms Authentication issues based on windows user?

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, forms-authentication, visual-studio-lightswitch

First my apologies if I failed to find an answer searching - I tried a variety of search topics but none that were directly related.

I have a Lightswitch app deployed and working fine, running on IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008. It is an internal intranet app only.

I am using only FORMS AUTHENTICATION, all others are disabled.

The app works fine for MOST windows users.
However, some windows users get nothing but a blank screen - no login, no "loading..." and no silverlight "98%" display.

In the IIS log, I don't even see where it looks like it is being accessed when they attempt to load the app?

So, my question is, since this is FORMS authentication only, what could be causing it to NOT work based on which windows user is trying to run the app?

In other words, on the same Windows 7 machine, it works for 10 users, but not for others.
by the way, the application is remote - it is not running on the local machine.

The users ARE able to access the other ASP.NET applications hosted by the same IIS server in the same root inetpub folder.

The lightswitch application is using the ASP.NET v4.0 Classic app pool in calssic managed pipeline mode.

Any help greatly appreciated!!!
Happy to post any details/config/logs - I did not do so yet as I wasn't sure what would be most useful....

Comment: Upon further research;

The user CAN login to the LS app using Firefox.
the error reported in IE is;

Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight
2 Application Code: 2103 Category:
InitializeError Message: 2103 An error
has occurred Code: 0

Researching this error, I found almost all references related to having changes the application NAMESPACE and not updated the startup object, which is not the case here.

So I am at a loss as to why it only happens in IE ?

Answer (score 0):

On the users machine you need to use Fiddler or the F12 tools in Internet Explorer to see exactly what calls are being made to the server and which ones are failing. LightSwitch is just an ASP.net website that launches a Silverlight application.

So the only other thing I can think of is that those users do not have Silverlight installed on their machines?

Comment: The same [windows] user can successfully run the application on other computers. And other users can run the application on this machine.  so it seems to be tied to windows users on certain machines.

Answer (score 0):

The users need to install the latest version of Silverlight.  Apps built with LightSwitch 2011 require v4 or above and those built with LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012 require v5

[Silverlight Installation](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx)

Comment: Dave - I am confused. if the USER did not have silverlight installed - why then does it work in Firefox for them ?